# Printing names of missing function arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function, arguments

One programming language feature that I consider essential is the automatic printing of missing named arguments, since it makes debugging much easier.

However, I haven't yet found an easy way to do this in Ruby. This code example prints `wrong number of arguments (1 for 3) (ArgumentError)` instead of printing the names of each missing argument:

```
def add_three_numbers(num1, num2, num3)
    puts(num1 + num2 + num3)
end    

add_three_numbers(num2:3)
```

I've found one way to print the missing function argument names, but it's very verbose and redundant: is there a less redundant way to print the names of the missing function arguments?

```
def add_three_numbers(num1=nil, num2=nil, num3=nil)
    errorToPrint = ""
    if(num1 == nil)
        error_to_print += "num1 is undefined, "
    end
    if(num2 == nil)
        error_to_print += "num2 is undefined, "
    end
    if(num3 == nil)
        error_to_print += "num3 is undefined, "
    end
    if(error_to_print != "")
        throw error_to_print
    end

    puts(num1 + num2 + num3)
end

add_three_numbers(num1:1)
```

Comment: @AndersonGreen While you can write either camelCase or snake_case, your code will be far more consistent with the Ruby libraries (including the standard library) and authors if you stick to snake_case.

Comment: Why is the name of the argument essential? What is the real issue here? You're probably getting downvotes because this seems rather silly (like "I would prefer it if the `def` keyword were capitalized — any way to do that?").

Comment: @Chuck It isn't always easy to remember the name of every single parameter for a function, especially if the function has a lot of parameters. That's why I need to see the names of the missing parameters whenever I call a function with named arguments.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: It sounds like you want a tool that shows you the parameters *when you're writing the call* rather than an error message that says the names of arguments you've forgotten at runtime. Would you say that's on track?

Comment: @Chuck That would be a better solution, but it would be much more difficult to implement. I wonder if any Ruby IDEs have this feature built-in.

Comment: For very small values of "essential".

Comment: @DaveNewton I only consider it to be an "essential" language feature because it has saved me countless hours of debugging effort: Python 3, for instance, prints the names of missing parameters whenever a named argument is missing. This makes it immediately clear which parameters need to be included.

Comment: They're ordered, you know which one is missing. Also, nil might be a valid value. Named parameters didn't even exist until Ruby 2. I'd be a little surprised if normal testing wasn't enough to catch these errors long before those countless hours.

Comment: @DaveNewton That doesn't entirely defeat its purpose: I still need to generate the names of the missing parameters when I'm working with dozens of functions that each take several named arguments, since it would otherwise be extremely difficult to remember the name of every single parameter in each function. (By default, this is how Python 3 handles named arguments: I'm surprised that most other programming languages don't print the names of the missing named parameters as well).

Comment: Why do you need to remember the names of several parameters for dozens of functions? I guess I simply haven't seen this as a significant problem across decades of programming in dynamic languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A concise solution to this problem [is given here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194880/an-accurate-answer-to-one-of-my-questions-was-deleted-how-can-i-recover-it?lq=1#194892), so I'm sharing it for all who come by in the future.

```
def add_three_numbers num1 = nil, num2 = nil, num3 = nil
  undefined = local_variables.select{|var| eval(var.to_s).nil?} - [:undefined]
  puts "#{undefined.join(", ")} are undefined" unless undefined.empty?
end

add_three_numbers
# => num1, num2, num3 are undefined

add_three_numbers(1)
# => num2, num3 are undefined
```

The answer was deleted by its original poster, but it has since been recovered.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that it does indeed make things clearer, it's worth noting that the reason Ruby doesn't do this is likely because it would be very hard, perhaps prohibitively hard, to get right.

If the problem looks simple, that's because the example is simple. The solution sawa has presented may work as advertised, but I can think of ways to define methods that this wouldn't work for.

It feels a little like you're fighting the structure of the language to restore what you're used to, which is natural when you're trying it out a new language. I would encourage you to let this go for the moment, just go with the flow, and come back to this later once you've picked up a little more Ruby.

Ruby has some great debugging and documentation tools that make finding out the missing method argument names simple. Check out [ri](http://samuelmullen.com/2012/01/up-and-running-with-ruby-interactive-ri/), [RDoc, and gem server](http://www.mikeperham.com/2010/12/16/using-rdoc/), all of which ship with Ruby. If you want something deeper, I can also recommend [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger).

Comment: @AndersonGreen His solution was to use `local_variables`, which you can learn more about in the [standard library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-local_variables). It simply returns a list of local variables, some of which may be the argument names. You could then use `eval` or one of its friends to find the value. I'd encourage you to play with it, but not to use it any kind of production environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this unless you want to hack Ruby and compile your own custom version.

If your problem is just remembering what the parameters to the method are, most major programming editors have some "jump to definition" functionality. For example, I tend to use Sublime Text. If I need to remember what the parameters of a method are, I just hit command-option-down and it shows me the method definition.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to do this, but the answer that explained how to do it was deleted by its poster ([for the reasons described here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194888/why-is-the-moderator-trying-to-hide-the-fact)). I hope that the answer will be undeleted eventually, since I am now unable to access it.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: That one still requires you to stick it in every single method, and it unfortunately doesn't work in the general case, as it can't distinguish between passing nil and forgetting to pass an argument.